# Don't fire onmouseout when mouse moves to something overlaying the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe `#viewer` and an absolutely positioned element `#appear_above_viewer` that appears above it. I want `#appear_above_viewer` to fade in when the mouse goes over `#viewer`, and fade out when the mouse leaves.

So far I have this code:

```
$("#viewer").hover(
    function(){ $("#appear_above_viewer").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'slow'); },
    function(){ $("#appear_above_viewer").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 'slow'); }
);
```

It seems to work, until you hover your mouse over `#appear_above_viewer`, and it conveniently disappears. I presume this is because an absolutely positioned element is considered something different to the iframe, and it's position on the screen makes no difference.

I want `#appear_above_viewer` to only disappear when the mouse leaves `#viewer`, and anything above it entirely. Is this possible?

(I've read other questions about this but none of them seem to work for my situation)

Comment: You'll have to manually calculate with mouse coordinates and the position of `#viewer`

Comment: Something as seemingly simple as this is that complex?

Comment: Yes because it's not a child of the iframe, therefore you can't use something like `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` or playing with the event propagation...

Comment: When you say above do you mean an overlay, or higher up on the screen?

Comment: Overlay. Sorry for confusion, will change title.

Comment: You could try to set [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) for the `#appear_above_viewer`, though it's not cross-browser...

Comment: @Teemu I do need IE support unfortunately. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @DuncanNZ In the legacy event model of the IE there are `event.toElement` and `event.fromElement` properties, quite similar to `relatedTarget`. You could try these with IE.

Answer (score 0):

Still not positive I know exactly what behavior is expected, but you likely just need to apply the `pointer-events` attribute in css set to `none` on your `appear_above_viewer`.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bcX8/) demonstrating something similar to what I think you want.

EDIT

You can use this question for a cross-browser solution:

[Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements/4839672#4839672)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
onmouseout =function(e){
   if ( e && e.preventDefault )
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    else
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    return false;
  }
```